# Kubernetes client go couldn't find module

Tags: go, kubernetes, go-modules, kubernetes-go-client, go-packages

I'm trying to connect to my local Kubernetes cluster hosted on `minikube`, [here's the code for the same](https://gist.github.com/rajatsing/af7dddfabd3087e72998a3b3be935f7b), now when I do `go run minikube.go`, it gives me an error saying:

```
../../../pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v11.0.0+incompatible/kubernetes/scheme/register.go:26:2: module k8s.io/api@latest found (v0.19.0), but does not contain package k8s.io/api/auditregistration/v1alpha1`.
```

Now, I tried to manually install the package using `go get` then I found out that this package does not exist.
How can I make it work and fix this?.
My [go.mod file](https://gist.github.com/rajatsing/c728c6a53e91d1f75d4bb3cdd97f4bae) in case anyone wants to see that.

Comment: try `go mod download`

Comment: @kozmo noo, it didn't worked, look at the error :), its pointing to a package that does not exist :/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Always specify matching versions of all three k8s.io/... components in your `go.mod` file

```
require (
    ...
    k8s.io/api v0.19.0
    k8s.io/apimachinery v0.19.0
    k8s.io/client-go v0.19.0
    ...
)
```

Comment: Where exactly am I supposed to make changes?.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the correct `go.mod` file..just copy it

Comment: Thanks Arghya, this worked, now I can connect my k8s client with my minikibe cluster :)

Comment: But @Arghya, it started to give me an error saying 
`./minikube.go:18:45: not enough arguments in call to clientset.CoreV1().Pods("").List
        have ("k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1".ListOptions)
        want (context.Context, "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1".ListOptions)`

Comment: Try this examole..if you face issue please ask a new question https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/out-of-cluster-client-configuration/main.go

Comment: Thanks for posting the workaround. This saved me few hours in troubleshooting whats going on!