# Could not import ... (no required module provides package)

Tags: go, kubernetes, module

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.martin-helmich.de/en/blog/kubernetes-crd-client.html).

I initialised my project and got the dependencies via

```
go mod init github.com/martin-helmich/kubernetes-crd-example
go get k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.0
go get k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.17.0
```

I have a Go file that uses `import metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"`.

VS Code shows me `could not import k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1 (no required module provides package "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1")`. What am I doing wrong here? Is my Go installation not correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes client go couldn't find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63655419/kubernetes-client-go-couldnt-find-module)

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, having the same problem with VS Code with a different package, so probably something with VS Code Go integration.. Did you find the answer?

Comment: did you test it with proxy? didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Go module cache directory (usually located at `$GOPATH/pkg/mod`).
If the packages you've installed not found try this:

`go get k8s.io/client-go@latest`

`go get k8s.io/apimachinery@latest`